# Content Service exception when ItemType Query is on the filesystem

Tags: content-delivery, web8

We are upgrading a `Tridion 2011 SP1` setup to `Web 8.1`. We had everything on the filesystem (jsp pages, linking info, …). While upgrading, we are moving to the new `REST-api` using the client libraries and the content service. This works well, but it seems there is an issue with the `Content Service` when trying to store the `ItemType` `Query` on the file system.

In that case the `Content Service` won't start and generates an exception. When we move the `Query` `ItemType` to the database everything work. Yet, this is not an option in production. Is there a fix for this so that we can also move `ItemType` `Query` to the filesystem?

Comment: I think ItemType Query in File System was actually dropped in 2013, so you may have a bigger issue than this. In 2011 SP1 we deprecated metadata on the file system, and I think this was a consequence of that move. Maybe someone from the Content Delivery Team will answer here with more detail

Comment: I don't use Query, but aparently the content service needs this otherwise it won't start. If it's dropped, why is that type still documented (http://bit.ly/2d9xzMw)? Also, we have multiple 2013 clients using FS only storage.

Comment: Fair questions. I don't know the answers :) If you don't get any answer here, it might be worth opening a ticket with support to make sure it reaches the people who know the answer.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, I already did, though, often Stack Exchange is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, support was faster and there is a hotfix for this: `CD_8.1.1.1957`

I have yet to test this.

Comment: It really depends on the nature of the question. Some questions only support and R&D can answer, in which case Support will likely be faster. Good to hear there was a fix already.

Comment: Yes nice to hear there's a fix and Paul-Marie was very fast in answering.